# How to get element by class name with Jsoup?

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I'm trying to extract some data from yahoo finance pages in Android.

Both the summary page and the historical prices page of a specific stock contain many td with class="yfnc_tabledata1", from which I need to extract the numbers. I could easily extract the data inside these td in the historical prices page, like here:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=LUX.MI").get();
            Elements html = document.getElementsByClass("yfnc_tabledata1");
```

But it seems this same snippet is not working with the summary page, like here:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=LUX.MI").get();
            Elements html = document.getElementsByClass("yfnc_tabledata1");
```

After reading other questions I also tried the following 3 approaches, but without success:

```
Elements html = document.select(".yfnc_tabledata1");
html.size() = 0
```

---

```
Elements html = document.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("class", "yfnc_tabledata1");
html.size() = 0
```

---

```
Element el = document.getElementById("table#table1");
Elements html = el.getAllElements();
html.size() = error due for el being null
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here a snippet of the summary page from which I can't extract data:

```html
<div class="yui-u first yfi-start-content">
  <div class="yfi_quote_summary">
    <div id="yfi_quote_summary_data" class="rtq_table">
      <table id="table1">
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="48%">Prev Close:</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">61.15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="48%">Open:</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">61.45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="48%">Bid:</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <span id="yfs_b00_lux.mi">61.20</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="48%">Ask:</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <span id="yfs_a00_lux.mi">61.30</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="48%">1y Target Est:</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">N/A</td>
        </tr><tr><th scope="row" width="48%">Beta:</th>
        <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">N/A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="54%">Next Earnings Date:</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">N/A</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table id="table2">
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="48%">Day's Range:</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <span>
              <span id="yfs_g53_lux.mi">60.75</span>
            </span> - 
            <span>
            <span id="yfs_h53_lux.mi">61.60</span>
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="48%">52wk Range:</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <span>34.74</span>
            - <span>62.50</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="48%">Volume:</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <span id="yfs_v53_lux.mi">1,057,884</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="48%">Avg Vol 
            <span class="small">(3m)</span>
            :</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">740,908</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="48%">Market Cap:</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1"
              ><span id="yfs_j10_lux.mi">29.36B</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="48%">P/E 
            <span class="small">(ttm)</span>
            :</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">42.28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" width="48%">EPS 
            <span class="small">(ttm)</span>
            :</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">1.45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="end"><th scope="row" width="48%">Div &amp; Yield:</th>
          <td class="yfnc_tabledata1">N/A (N/A) </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT1**:

I found why the same snippet doesn't work on both pages.
The snippet works fine with the historical prices page, and if I try to retrieve the html of that page, I can see that it's the same exact html I see in the view-source of that page in chrome. The same doesn't happen with the summary page: when I try to retrieve its html, it has nothing to do with the view-source in chrome, it's retrievin something different, I can't tell what exactly. So the question now is: how come this snippet is not retrieving the correct html of the page?

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=LUX.MI").get();
            temp = document.html();
```

Comment: Ok, found a solution to this problem, even though I still can't explain why Jsoup can't retrieve the correct html of the page. Anyway... adding another edit to the question

Comment: Try adding a userAgent in jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

> Solution originally found by OP:

**EDIT2- SOLUTION**:
In case happens to anyone else: if Jsoup.connect(url).get() for some reason doesn't retrieve the correct page, first get the HTML in a String without using Jsoup, and only after that parse the String with Jsoup.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://google.com");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); 
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

InputStream is = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    sb.append(line + "\n");

String html = sb.toString();
is.close();
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Another solution...

This is a variant of OP's solution. Here, we give Jsoup the inputstream provided by `httpclient` directly. Jsoup is able to parse inputstreams.

```
String url = "http://google.com";

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); 
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

InputStream is = entity.getContent();
Document document = Jsoup.parse(is, null, url);
is.close();
```

### ... but how to select elements by class name?

For selecting elements by class names, a simple CSS selector is needed. For example:

- **HTML**

```
<div class="container open">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

- **CSS selector**

Any selector in the list below can find the div presented in the previous HTML section.

```
div.container
div.open
div.container.open
```

### It still doesn't work...

Some times this won't work because the final HTML you can see in the browser is generated on the fly by some javascript code. Jsoup (1.8.3 as of this writing) doesn't have Javascript support. It can't run the javascript.